# MySQL - Using SELECT for IF statement condition in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to execute, in a stored procedure, a certain set of statements if, in table `my_table` there is exactly one row with value `value` in column `column_name`. I have tried the following, but I get a syntax error:

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE column_name = value) = 1) THEN
    BEGIN
    END;
END IF;
```

For context: In my procedure I create a temporary table at some point, where I store a list of values. Then later on in the procedure, I want to check if a given value is present in that temporary table.

Comment: MySQL only supports the `IF` statement in programming blocks such as stored procedures.  You cannot write code this way.

Comment: I forgot to add, but this is in a stored procedure.

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: There is a `then` missing.

Comment: @Solarflare correct. I had the THEN in my code. Just forgot to put it here.

Comment: Well, with a `then`, the syntax is correct and this code should work (if used correctly in a procedure, e.g. you added the delimiter and such). Adding the errormessage and more code (since that cannot be all there is, as it should not generate an error, so the problem will likely lie somewhere else) will be the next step to identify the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be better to structure it more like this

```
BEGIN
DECLARE myCOUNT INTEGER;

SELECT COUNT(*) 
INTO myCount
FROM my_table
WHERE column_name=value; 

IF (myCount = 1) THEN
 -- do stuff
END IF;

END;
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing it this way. But was just wondering if there was a way to do it without creating an auxiliary variable.

Comment: I think the only other way to do it would be to use a CURSOR and FETCH - but given you only ever return one row from that query, that's more complicated without any real benefit. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html  - I  don't think MySQL supports implicit cursors, and they are generally frowned on anyway (FOR i IN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but I'll guess an "upsert" -- update a record if it exists, otherwise insert a new record.

In any case, if you are trying to ensure that `name` is unique in `my_table`, then this is not the right approach at all.  Instead, declare a unique index/constraint so the database ensures the data integrity:

```
create unique index unq_my_table_name on my_table(name);
```

You can then use `insert . . . on duplicate key update` to modify the records in the database.

Comment: In my procedure I create a temporary table at some point, where I store a list of values. Then later on in the procedure, I want to check if a given value is present in that temporary table.